# How to secure a publicly available lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to secure a **public lambda** on **my website**. The users will **not be authenticated** when they access it. Any ideas how to do this ?

Jim

Comment: How do you make a public Lambda?

Comment: if you have it available without authentication, opens and accessible, then it's public.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you're referring to the API Gateway not the Lambda function itself. By default, a Lambda function can only be called from the same AWS account.

Comment: @Jimi there's a distinction between an unauthenticated *user* and an unauthenticated *request*.  Unless your web site is entirely static, you should be able generate pre-signed URLs for API Gateway when you render the page that invokes it... the same way you can for S3. Or a CSRF-like mechanism with tokens.  A little more insight into your site's implementation and a general description of the function's purpose might be helpful.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It is a wrong suggestion and junk solution for presigned urls. It is a public lambda and want to secure only his website. COR's is the only solution.

Comment: Kannaiyan, I am very interested in this thread. Can you recommend a CORS policy that will provide security? My understanding of CORS is that it is the practice of the browser respecting CORS, which means that a rogue third party can just ignore CORS, falsify origin, etc.

Comment: @Jimi can you help me out how you solve this problem or anyone here can help me out, it would be really great

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Lambda functions are not available to the public without authorization. Invoking Lambda requires AWS credentials. Unauthenticated users cannot directly access Lambda. The exception is if you are using API Gateway in front of your Lambda functions.

Access to AWS Lambda requires credentials that AWS can use to authenticate your requests. Those credentials must have permissions to access AWS resources, such as an AWS Lambda function or an Amazon S3 bucket.

[Authentication and Access Control for AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-auth-and-access-control.html)

[Control Access in API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

- This link would be helpful with screenshots given.
  [Fix the issue using this link](https://www.intelligentdiscovery.io/controls/lambda/aws-lambda-public-access)
- Ideally issue is that access is give with * in resources or any of the policy statement which is causing this issue.